# $(A\subseteq B)\wedge (|A|=|B|) \implies A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. I'm trying to prove that, if $A\subseteq B$ and there exists a bijection $f:A\to B$, then $A=B$ or rather $B\subseteq A$. My attempt at a proof:

Choose $y\in B$, there exists $f^{-1}:B\to A$ an inverse map to $f$. Therefore $(f\circ f^{-1})(y)\in B \implies f^{-1}(y)\in f^{-1}(B)=A\subseteq B$. Then we have $y\in B \implies y\in f(B)$, from that I infered $B\subseteq f(B) \subseteq f(A) = B$. So I get $f(A)=f(B)$. That is where I got stuck. Can I conclude that $A=B$ by injectivity of $f$? How do I fully justify this last step?

Comment: A priori $f(y)$ might not be defined for all $y\in B$, as we only know that $A\subset B$ at first. I would prove that statement via contradiction. Assume $A\neq B$, i.e., $A$ is a proper subset of $B$, hence there exists an element $b\in B$ with $b\neq A$. But as $A\subset B$, and both have the same finite number of elements, this is a contradiction, proving that actually $A=B$.

Comment: Seems like the easiest way to prove this would be via induction on $\vert A \vert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ is everything in $B$ that's not in $A$, then $B = A \sqcup B$. So once you get $f(A) = f(B)$, you have $f(A) = f(A \sqcup C) = f(A) \cup f(C) $.

I.e. $f(A) = f(A) \cup f(C) $, which means $f(C) \subset f(A)$. But $f$ is a bijection, and $A$ and $C$ are disjoint, so their images are disjoint. From that, you can conclude $f(C) = \emptyset$, and thus $C = \emptyset$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Given ${A}\subseteq{B}$ and $|{A}|=|{B}|$, Asm ${A}\ne {B}$, then
$$
{A}\subseteq{B}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
{B}=\{{A},{b}_{1},\ldots\} 
\quad \Longrightarrow\quad
|{B}|>|{A}| 
\quad \Rightarrow \Leftarrow
 $$

Comment: Yes, except I'm thinking that you want to conclude that $|B|>|A|$ for a contradiction.